# Unable to use XSSF with Excel 2007

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am having tough time getting to read data from excel 2007. I am using XSSF to read data from a specific cell of excel but keep getting error -

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setSaveAggressiveNamespaces()Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:46)`

This is my piece of code:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
    InputStream ins = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Tarun3Kumar\\Desktop\\test.xlsx"); 
    XSSFWorkbook xwb = new XSSFWorkbook(ins);
    XSSFSheet sheet = xwb.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
    System.out.println("a");
}
```

I have following jars added to build path -

`poi-3.6
poi-ooxml-3.6
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.6
x-bean.jar`

I could only figure out that `setSaveAggressiveNamespaces` has replaced `setSaveAggresiveNamespaces`....

Comment: My Mistake,I should be using version 2.4.0 of xbean!
Let me see if u succeed after using this.

Comment: Thanks, I faced the same problem. Followed your hint.
I had : poi-3.6 poi-ooxml-3.6 poi-ooxml-schemas-3.6 x-bean.jar in eclipse liberary.
xlsx failed with the same error.
Then I added : xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar and dom4j-1.6.1.jar
xlsx and xls both working fine now. I didn't change the order to bring xmlbeans to the top.

Thx for the tip.
G-

Comment: Got it working :)
had to add one more jar named - dom4j.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is other issue happen to be: xbean.jar and xmlbeans.jar both have XmlOptions, but only xmlbeans.jar have method you want. I changed path order for xmlbeans.jar first and worked.