# Creating XLSX using POI API

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

I am Trying to create XLSX file using POI API but an error has been occurred..

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setSaveAggressiveNamespaces()Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:56)**

and i am not able to figure out the reason of this error please help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an older version of XmlBeans on your classpath. Apache POI requires XMLBeans 2.3 or newer (newer is fine, older isn't!). See the [components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) for details of the dependencies, which you also get in the binary download. Just remove the older version, make sure a new enough version of xmlbeans is present, and you should be fine!

Comment: Hi ...
 thanks for your reply yes the problem was because of xbean.jar when i replced this JAR from my build path it worked fine...

Comment: Glad it worked. Please accept the answer when you have a minute, so everyone else knows it was the correct solution!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031437/unable-to-use-xssf-with-excel-2007) is a similar question. The problem seems to be either having both xbean.jar and xmlbeans.jar in your classpath or dom4j.jar missing from the classpath.

Comment: Hi Buddy...
thanks for your reply yes the problem was because of xbean.jar when i replced this JAR from my build path it worked fine...